# How to add multiply variables with YAML conditional insertion

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

I read this document https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion
but not like what demoed in the document, I need add three variables with same condition as below:

```
name: arm_temp
resources:
   repositories:
   - repository: self
     type: git
variables:
  - ${{ if in(lower(coalesce(variables['ENV'], variables['Build.SourceBranchName'])), 'release', 'prod') }}:
    - newEnv: 'Prod'
    - account: '$(ACCOUNT)'
    - password: '$(PASSWORD)'
  - ${{ if eq(lower(coalesce(variables['ENV'], variables['Build.SourceBranchName'])), 'qa') }}:
    - newEnv: 'QA'
    - account: '$(ACCOUNT)'
    - password: '$(PASSWORD)'
  - resGroupName: ${{ format('RESGROUP-{0}', variables['newEnv']) }}
```

ACCOUNT, PASSWORD and ENV are variables defined in azure build pipeline
but I always get error before run the build pipeline.

and error notification is about line under the if conditiona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Yaml sample, it seems that the Yaml format has some issues.

You could refer to the following YAML Sample:

```
variables:
  ${{ if in(lower(coalesce(variables['ENV'], variables['Build.SourceBranchName'])), 'release', 'prod') }}: 
    newEnv: 'Prod'
    account: $(myaccount)
    password: $(mypassword)
  ${{ if eq(lower(coalesce(variables['ENV'], variables['Build.SourceBranchName'])), 'qa') }}: 
    newEnv: 'QA'
    account: $(myaccount)
    password: $(mypassword)
  resGroupName: ${{ format('RESGROUP-{0}', variables['newEnv']) }}
pool:
   vmimage: windows-latest
steps:
- script: |
     echo $(newEnv)
     echo $(account)
     echo $(password)
```

Variable:

[image]

Result:

[image]

**Note:** You need to change the variable name `$(ACCOUNT)` `$(PASSWORD)`. They cannot have the same name as the variable defined in yaml(`$(account), $(password)`). Or the variable couldn't pass successfully.

Comment: thanks for this, I tried with it , but the out put is: 
$(newEnv)
$(account)
$(password)

Comment: Hi @frank. You need to make sure that  the condition of the if expression is met. Then the variable will be set. Or it will not set the correct variable

Comment: I suggest you can simplify the if expression for testing

Comment: thanks for pointing out this, seems there is something wrong with my condition.